# Flutter - ListWheelScrollView Magnifier not magnifying image?

Tags: flutter

I am testing the ListWheelScrollView, and noticed the magnifier is skipping images and icons.
Can we change that somehow?
 Here is a sample.
Also, can we change the colors of the selected items? Eg have the current zoomed item colored, the others as black and white.

[image]

```
List<Widget> items = [
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_activity, size: 50),
    title: Text('Activity'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_airport, size: 50),
    title: Text('Airport'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_atm, size: 50),
    title: Text('ATM'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_bar, size: 50),
    title: Text('Bar'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_cafe, size: 50),
    title: Text('Cafe'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_car_wash, size: 50),
    title: Text('Car Wash'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_convenience_store, size: 50),
    title: Text('Heart Shaker'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_dining, size: 50),
    title: Text('Dining'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_drink, size: 50),
    title: Text('Drink'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_florist, size: 50),
    title: Text('Florist'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station, size: 50),
    title: Text('Gas Station'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store, size: 50),
    title: Text('Grocery Store'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
];

        Container(
          height: 400,
          child: ListWheelScrollView(
            itemExtent: 75,
            children: items,
            useMagnifier: true,
            magnification: 1.5,
            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
            diameterRatio: 4,
            perspective: 0.0000000001,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (index) => {print(index)},
          ),
        )
```

Comment: i would say that left icon is pushed to the far left thus not visible - for testing wrap `ListTile` with `Padding` on the left side so that the icon is placed a bit more to the center

Comment: That works, but this seems like a bug

Answer (score 0):

Google came back at github meanwhile with the solution. set offAxisFraction to .5
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59163

Answer (score 0):

Convert svg icons into ttf font and use generated IconData.
In this case images will be correct displays and supports magnify and opacity properties

SVG -> TTF converter: https://www.fluttericon.com/

add generated ttf as font asset:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: generated_font_family
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/assets/generated_font.ttf
```

Example of apply icon from font:

```
Icon(
  GeneratedIconsData.anyIcon,
)
```